# How to correctly build an Adobe Extension?

Tags: javascript, adobe, manifest, extendscript, after-effects

Hello I've just completed my first extension for Adobe After Effects but now I don't understand how to build it as zxp file. I don't need to sell it or publish it in some marketplace, I just want to send it to a friend where he can simply install it using zxp installer. I don't find any tutorial to guide me in this process, so I'd like to ask you if it is necessary to add a signature (even if it will not distribute) or which is the right procedure to make it works. Thank you very much

Following the comment of a user, I simply tried to zip the extension folder and renamed it from zip to zxp, but I just receive a 401error when I try to install the extension with zxp installer

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Bolt-CEP which is a great tool to get all the scaffolding done.  Also a great community building around it.  Check out:

https://github.com/hyperbrew/bolt-cep